# Trying to containerize Intellj Maven project using a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, maven, intellij-idea, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17 
COPY ./out/production/Company /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
ENTRYPOINT ["java","Main"]
```

When I run the Dockerfile I get errors because my project is using a Maven dependency: `org.json`

I need help editing my Dockerfile to include this Maven dependency

Comment: Are you using maven to manage your build? IE, I assume you have a `pom.xml` defined along with all the dependencies that your project uses ya?

Comment: Yes, correct. I am using the pom.xml to handle the dependencies

Comment: You need to set the classpath.  If you am unsure how this applies here, some studying will pay very well off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way then for you is to use the `jib` plugin.

Add the plugin to your project, then create an `entrypoint.sh` that tells Docker how to start the app.

Then execute the plugin to build the Docker image. It will figure out all the dependencies and bundle it into the Docker image.

Link: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making my maven project into a jar file and that fixed the dependency problem.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:17
ADD out/artifacts/Company_jar/Company.jar Company.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","Company.jar"]
```

There are multiple solutions so I gave the first response as the answer because I would have used the plugin if not for the jar solution.